# Joining columns from different tables without duplicating

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the table `TableA` with 100 rows in it. It has a column `loanid`, which may have duplicates.

I need to `join` with the other table  `TableB`, which has a column `loanid`, to join with.

But, the `loanid` in `tableB` may or may not be in `tableA`.

So if I take a `right join` or `left join`, I want the result to be same as 100.

Since there is a matching and unmatching `loanid` in both table, there is a chance of result to be not 100 rows, if I do a `right join` or `left join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe you want a `left join`:

```
select . . .
from tablea a left join
     tableb b
     on a.loanid = b.loanid;
```

This keeps every row in `tablea` along with all matching rows in `tableb`.  From your description, `tableb` doesn't have duplicates, so this will keep everything in `tablea` with no duplicates.

If `tableb` had duplicates and you wanted one arbitrary row, then you can use `outer apply`:

```
select . . .
from tablea a outer apply
     (select top 1 b.*
      from tableb b
      where a.loanid = b.loanid
     ) b;
```

Comment: i tried the first approach, but i am not getting 100 rows , i getting 123 rows

Comment: But will i get the corresponding column values from tableb for matching loanid in tablea ?